# Allreduce with user defined function and MPI_BOTTOM

Tags: c++, mpi

Consider the following program that is supposed to do some stupid addition of `double`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <mpi.h>

void add(void* invec, void* inoutvec, int* len, MPI_Datatype*)
{
    double* a = reinterpret_cast <double*> (inoutvec);
    double* b = reinterpret_cast <double*> (invec);

    for (int i = 0; i != *len; ++i)
    {
        a[i] += b[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    std::vector<double> buffer = { 2.0, 3.0 };

    MPI_Op operation;
    MPI_Op_create(add, 1, &operation);

    MPI_Datatype types[1];
    MPI_Aint addresses[1];
    int lengths[1];
    int count = 1;

    MPI_Get_address(buffer.data(), &addresses[0]);
    lengths[0] = buffer.size();
    types[0] = MPI_DOUBLE;

    MPI_Datatype type;
    MPI_Type_create_struct(count, lengths, addresses, types, &type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);

    MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, MPI_BOTTOM, 1, type, operation, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Type_free(&type);
    MPI_Op_free(&operation);
    MPI_Finalize();

    std::cout << buffer[0] << " " << buffer[1] << "\n";
}
```

Because this is part of larger program where the data I want to send is 1) on the heap and 2) consists of different types I think I have to use a user-defined type.

Now something must be wrong here because the program crashes when run with `mpirun -n 2 ./a.out`. The backtrace from gdb is:

```
#0  __memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:158
#1  0x00007ffff65de460 in non_overlap_copy_content_same_ddt () from /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff180a69b in ompi_coll_tuned_allreduce_intra_recursivedoubling () from /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so
#3  0x00007ffff793bb8b in PMPI_Allreduce () from /usr/local/lib/libmpi.so.1
#4  0x00000000004088b6 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd708) at mpi_test.cpp:39
```

Line 39 is the `MPI_Allreduce` call. This is probably a dumb mistake, but after staring on it for hours I still don't see it. Does anyone spot the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if such use of `MPI_BOTTOM` is allowed by the standard. That it crashes (confirmed also with Open MPI 1.10.2) is likely a bug in Open MPI. Its implementation of `MPI_Allreduce` allocates a temporary buffer and then tries to copy the content of the receive buffer into it assuming that the same datatype is used for both buffers. That simply doesn't work with types with absolute addresses as the address of the temporary buffer is nowhere near zero (in Open MPI, `MPI_BOTTOM == NULL`). Post to the [Open MPI User list](https://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/ompi.php).

Comment: I just tried with MPICH 3.0.4 which seems to work. But my `add` is definetely wrong, `inoutvec` is `NULL` as it probably should be (`MPI_BOTTOM`), and `invec` has a slightly higher address.

Comment: Your `add` is wrong because you fail to properly work with the datatype. `inoutvec` is `NULL` because that is what `MPI_BOTTOM` is on systems with contiguous (non-segmented) address spaces. `invec` is slightly higher since MPICH properly adjusts the address of the temporary buffer by the lower bound of the datatype. But you are processing the parameters of `add` as if both vectors are `MPI_DOUBLE`, failing to account the lower bound of the datatype.

Comment: Note that all predefined MPI datatypes, including `MPI_DOUBLE`, have their lower bound equal to zero, which means that the buffer pointer points directly to the beginning of the data. This is not the case with your `type`, which has a lower bound equal to `&buffer[0]`. When you add that lower bound to the value of `MPI_BOTTOM` (NULL), you get the address of `buffer[0]`.

Comment: Have you reported the error to Open MPI or shall I do it?

Comment: I didn't and I can't right now, so go ahead if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** There is a bug in how Open MPI handles types with non-zero lower bounds (such as the one that you create when using absolute addresses) while performing in-place reduce-to-all. It seems to exist in all versions, including the development branch. The status can be tracked by following the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/1764).

---

Your `add` operator is wrong as you fail to account for the datatype's lower bound. A proper solution would be something like:

```
void add(void* invec, void* inoutvec, int* len, MPI_Datatype* datatype)
{
    MPI_Aint lb, extent;
    MPI_Type_get_true_extent(*datatype, &lb, &extent);

    double* a = reinterpret_cast <double*> (reinterpret_cast <char*>(inoutvec) + lb);
    double* b = reinterpret_cast <double*> (reinterpret_cast <char*>(invec) + lb);

    for (int i = 0; i != *len; ++i)
    {
        a[i] += b[i];
    }
}
```

This will access the data correctly but is still wrong. `*len` will be 1 as that is what you pass to `MPI_Allreduce` but there are two doubles behind each element. The correctly written operator will either use the type introspection mechanism to obtain the length of the block of doubles and multiply `*len` by it or simply hardcode the vector length to be two:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2*(*len); i++)
{
    a[i] += b[i];
}
```

Comment: This definitely works with MPICH 3.0.4. Could you also add the bugreport for OpenMPI?

Comment: Done. I've edited the answer and added a link to the issue tracker.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!